# How to get statistics from Scopus

Tags: scopus

I am working on a survey and I would like to retrieve statistics on the number of papers published within two given years (e.g. 1990 and 2018).

In a paper, for instance (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apm.2009.10.005), I have seen that such statistics can be obtained from Scopus, but I have no clue how to get those stats.

I would appreciate if you could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that one has to use the net / proxy of a library (school) that has access to SCOPUS so that one can make use of the search engine some other data and stats. Regards